# sharepoint app with "User Profile"-permission fails

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom

I have a provier hosted app. It works well, but as soon as I asks for user profile permission (by adding it to manifest file), it says I need permission from Tenant admin. I have got permission approved and can see it in my app-permission overview. When I return to the app and click [...]--> About it still says I need permission.

The app works if I dont ask for user profile permission (and dont query any ups data)

Comment: i think you need to trust that app at tenant level in order to get the proper permissions

Comment: How do you mean? I have a tentant Admin account. I have approved the app in the "appcatalog/apprequest"-page